# Dataframe.loc does not work on multiple index , very simple

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyLXX.png): [As you can see, I have the index "State" and "City"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyLXX.png)

And I want to filter by state using loc, for example using:

```
nuevo4.loc["Bulgaria"]
```

(The name of the Dataframe is "nuevo4"), but instead of getting the results, I want I get the error:

> KeyError: 'Bulgaria'

I read the loc documentation online and I cannot see the fail here, I'm sorry if this is too obvious, the names are well spelled, and that...

Comment: Can you include the concerned part of the dataset in the question (as text)? Also, please include any code you used for transformations done (if any).

Comment: Double check that you can find Bulgaria when you print the index: `print(nuevo4.index.levels[0])` There may be some whitespace issues.

Comment: Yep... it was a whitespace issue, so frustrasting!  Thank you so much man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You command should work see the below example.  You might have some whitespace issues with your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(-1,5), index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A',1), ('A',2),('B', 0), ('C', 1), ('C', 2)]))

print(df)

print(df.loc['A'])
```

Output:

```
      0   1   2   3   4
A 1   0   1   2   3   4
  2   5   6   7   8   9
B 0  10  11  12  13  14
C 1  15  16  17  18  19
  2  20  21  22  23  24
```

Using loc:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
1  0  1  2  3  4
2  5  6  7  8  9
```

Comment: Yep, I forgot to delete the whitsespaces ! So frustrating, thank you so much!